# UIWindow keyWindow changed notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cydia-substrate, logos

I'm creating a jailbreak tweak that adds a view to the UIWindow of whatever the current keyWindow is.  The problem is that whenever the keyWindow changes the view gets removed.

I'm using this

```
%hook SBApplication
-(void)willActivate {
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,53)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [window addSubview:view];
}
%end
```

is there another method that is better to use here or is there a notification that is sent whenever the window changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

Method called when a keyWindow is changed is in UIWindow and the method is

```
-(void)makeKeyWindow
```

just hook that and then add your subview!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a notification you can observe:

`UIWindowDidBecomeKey`

> Posted whenever a UIWindow object becomes the key window.
>   The notification object is the window object that has become key. This
>   notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.

[More in the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1621607-uiwindowdidbecomekey)